# React app not picking updated node module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a private made node package, which I publish to private registry, now when I just replace the dist folder inside node_modules in an application am using the package, the application still loads the original code, I have also confirmed that the files were updated but the app throws an error, and the surprising thing, in my IDE, it load the updates and I can navigate to the original code, here is the error am getting:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/layout/Layout.tsx 274:47-68
export 'OrganizationsLinkIcon' (imported as 'OrganizationsLinkIcon') was not found in '@getsote/react-core' (possible exports: CustomersLinkIcon)
```

And the dist file content (file too big so truncated to the most important parts):

```
export { OrganizationsLinkIcon, CustomersLinkIcon };
```

And...

```
declare const CustomersLinkIcon: (props: NavLinkProp) => JSX.Element;
declare const OrganizationsLinkIcon: (props: NavLinkProp) => JSX.Element;
```

Importation:

```
import { CustomersLinkIcon, OrganizationsLinkIcon } from '@getsote/react-core';
```

Am not sure if I am missing anything but this has been driving me crazy, any help here would be highly appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE:** I copy the dist folder locally in order to debug the package before publishing it, also I did restart the server on the application several times

Comment: "when I just replace the dist folder inside node_modules in an application am using the package, the application still loads the original code" 1. why would you do this? 2. Did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes I did, and I do to debug the package before I publish it